# Expectation of Absolute Value of Bernoulli Masked Function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say we have a real vector $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Is there a way to simplify the following expectation

$$
\mathbb{E}_{m\sim Bern(p)^n}\left[|\nabla f(\theta)^T(-\theta \otimes m)|\right]
$$

where $m$ is a vector of i.i.d. bernoulli variables of size $n$ and $\otimes$ is the element wise product.

Without the absolute value we can simplify to

$$
\mathbb{E}_{m\sim Bern(p)^n}\left[\nabla f(\theta)^T(-\theta \otimes m)\right] = -p \nabla f(\theta)^T\theta
$$

But I'm wondering if we can simplify the absolute value object without bounds (e.g. without using cauchy-schwarz, Lipschitz)?

Comment: Assuming $m \in \{ 0, 1\}^n $ then $\theta \otimes m \in \R^{n \times n}$ which implies your expectation should be a vector unlike the scalar that you have got. Perhaps you wanted to write something else?

Comment: @sudeep5221 $\otimes$ is a element wise product, so the result will be $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh so it is the Hadamard product? I thought it is the Kronecker product as $\otimes$ is usually used to denote Kronecker product. Thanks for the clarification.